# Cannot understand an equation related to impedance. (Power system analysis)

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, power-engineering

[image: **Part 1 of the example **]

[image: Part 2 of the example. Can someone explain how can we find |Z| term and also from where does the cosine term arrive at the final equation.]

Can someone explain how can we find |Z| term and also from where does the cosine term arrive at the final equation.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I can't get why |Z| is producing the result as provided in the text. I was expecting it to produce sqrt((wL)^2 + R^2) . Also why does the cosine term arrive at the final equation of v(t)? @user8055

Answer (score 1):

$\underline Z$ is, by definition, $\frac{\underline V}{\underline I}$.  So $\underline Z$ is not shown, but it comes from the calculation for $\underline V$ as a function of $\underline I$.

The magnitude and phase angle is computed from $\underline Z$, and are basic complex number calculations.

The cosine term in the final equation comes from the definition of $i(t)$ at the top of the example, which is in terms of $\cos \omega$.